# Can a metric use multiple Variables in a dashboard?

Tags: gooddata

Say there is metric that has records from multiple clients

`select count(id) WHERE variable`

Is there a way to have the metric use multiple variables which are defined in a dashboard? Something like 
`select count(id) WHERE variable_value1 OR variable_value1`.

The metric would appear on a dashboard that has either `variable_value1` or `variable_value2`. I've test using the OR logic, but the metric still shows data from both values instead filtering to whatever `variable_value` is on the dashboard.

I know a variable as a filter on the dashboard would do the same job, but users (that have unfiltered access to all variables values) want to have a fixed view per variable value in separate dashboard tabs and I'd like to avoid duplicating metrics for each variable value.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that can be done within the metric, but it depends on the data that you are looking at. The metric itself would look something like this:

`SELECT <metric> where <attribute> = <attribute_value1> AND <attribute> = <attribute_value2>`

You can replace the "AND" with an "OR" within in the metric as well. If you need further clarification, could you please provide a specific example? We would be glad to help you out here.

Thanks,

GoodData Support